# How to activate scopes with a select dropdown

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a dropdown list of options I'd like to activate different functions when selected.

Here's some HTML I'm using:

```
     <select>
            <option value="all">all</option>
            <option value="tasks">tasks</option>
     </select>
```

Here's some code from my model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :task, -> { where(ideas: true) }
end
```

And here's some code from my controller:

```
def index
    #display posts with the params sent through the search bar

    #display the posts with by the params sent through clicking a tag
    if params[:tag]
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").tagged_with(params[:tag])
    elsif params[:search]
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").tagged_with(params[:search])
    elsif params[:user]
        #will eventually be for user's profile page
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @posts=@user.posts
    else
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

end
```

Pretty basic.

When I select "tasks" I want the tasks scope to activate - essentially, I want all my posts with the nested attribute "task" (I'm using the cocoon gem to create different post types) to show up when I select the "task" option in my dropdown list.

Scopes may not be the best way to do it. If you have any other suggestions I would be happy to take them.

Comment: You could have your controller accept the dropdown selection and process it there, returning the results from the scope. I don't think there is a more automatic way of doing it. Can you supply your current controller code?

Comment: done - let me know if you need more than that. I'm not currently using any code in there to approach this. was kind of stuck, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I've become a fan of my controllers doing almost nothing. Instead they simply call another object and pass off the work. This allows you to basically forgo testing controllers. Instead this approach provides some nice PORO's that are easy to isolate and test.

In your example above I would have a controller like this.

```
def index
  finder = PostFinder.new(params)
  @posts = finder.posts
end
```

Now that your controller is stupid let this new object do the work

```
class PostFinder

  def initialize(args={})
    @posts = []
    find_posts(args)
  end

  def posts
    @posts
  end

  private

  def find_posts(args={})
    # Magic hidden code to find your posts
    #@posts << posts we found...
  end

end
```

For your scoping question you will want to make sure it is included in the search form submission

```
 <select name="scope">
        <option value="all">all</option>
        <option value="tasks">tasks</option>
 </select>
```

The it will be in the params. Your controller will pass these params to your `PostFinder` object and from there it is up to that object to contain the logic for how the params filter down the posts.

For example the `find_posts` method in `PostFinder` will access to this param

```
def find_posts(args={})
  if args[:scope]
    scoped_posts = Post.method(args[:scope]).call
  end
  # continue filter logic as needed
end
```

Comment: Okay so I've added this code and replaced :scope in the find_posts method with :task but its still not working. I am obviously missing something.

Comment: Please show what you have in `find_posts` and what the frontend form looks like. I suspect that you don't have the logic correct in the PORO.

Comment: @Bennick, `Post.send(args[:scope])` is very much vulnerable as `send` can  send message to `private` methods as well (you can image the consequences); its better to use `Post.method(args[:scope]).call` instead

Comment: @illusionist You are correct and the example has been updated. I'm really just trying to show Tara a good place to hold this sort of filtering logic.